# How to implement a subclassable Singleton in Java

Tags: java, design-patterns, singleton

I am looking for a way to implement an abstract class (or effectively abstract) that enforces only one instance of each subclass.

I am fairly sure this would be pretty simple to implement with a Factory but I would be interested to know if it can be done without knowing all subclass types, i.e a generic singleton enforcer class.

Right now I am mostly just playing around with the idea for something like this, So I am not looking for feedback that questions the design choice here.

The language I am working in is Java, but right now I am not necessarily worried about implementation details, Unless it is not possible in Java, then, of course, provide evidence that it is not possible.

Comment: It's not possible to enforce the Singleton pattern without a private constructor, which makes external subclassing impossible.

Comment: Take a look at [ask] and [help/on-topic]. This sort of open-ended question is not a great [SO] fit.

Comment: 'provide evidence that it is not possible' that's not how this works... as said by @pvg this is not [help/on-topic] and even if it were the burden of proof is on you.

Comment: Except for trivial applications, it's not possible to implement a singleton in Java. It's considered an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm wondering what it is you are trying to do. A couple of possibilities spring to mind and knowing where this is heading might help.

**Option 1**

So you could try to use an `enum` type as your abstract base class. Each enumeration constant is then guaranteed by the language to be a singleton. The enum can have abstract methods which the constants implement. This will work but compilation unit an get very big and hard to navigate if you have a lot of implementing constants and a lot of abstract methods to implement. You could of course delegate some of the work to helper classes if it starts to get out of hand.

**Option 2**

You could do is get the base class constructor to check it's actual type and store it in a static HashSet (or similar). If an entry already exists then you have two instances of the same singleton. Something like

```
public abstract class BaseClass {
    private static HashSet<Class<?>> instances = new HashSet<>();

    protected BaseClass() {
        checkInstances();
    }

    private synchronized void checkInstances() {
        boolean duplicate = instances.add(getClass());

        if (duplicate) {
           throw new RuntimeException("Duplicate class " + getClass().getName()); 
        }
    }
}
```

The disadvantage of this is that the error occurs at runtime and the code isn't especially pretty and as you can see you may need to consider synchronization of the set

**Option 3**

Your final option is simply not to ask the base class to enforce this restriction. It should probably the job of the derived classes to decided if they are singletons or not. A private constructor in the derived class is the easiest way to do that.

**Conclusion**

Personally I'd implement either option 1 or option 3 as you won't get run-time failures.

Comment: I came up with something similar to your "Option 2" but I think it is more cumbersome than I would like, and I don't think it would be completely clear to someone who hasn't used something like this before. So I will probably resort to not enforcing Singleton-ness.

Comment: I agree - Option to 2 ugly. IMHO enforcing singleton-ness should be a job for the singleton class its self and not for a class it extends.

Comment: old thread but I almost always use enums for sngletons because the ease in implementation and the inability to bypass the singleton via reflection.

Answer (score 0):

First, a generic singleton doesn't make sense.
A parent class should not be responsible of retrieving and managing instances of its subclasses.
It creates a strong coupling in both ways (parent->child and child->parent).

Second, as shmosel says, subclassing a singleton (without special artifact) is not possible.
The key of the singleton pattern is the lack of ability to instantiate the class outside the singleton class, so no public constructor has to be provided.
In these conditions, how subclass the singleton class ?

To allow subclassing a singleton class, you must have a public constructor while ensuring that you have no more than one instance of the class.
Inversion of control containers such as Spring may do that (It is an example of special artifact).

---

As a side note, I don't consider access modifier tweaking such as the `package-private` modifier that could allow to subclass a singleton but the limitation of it is that the singleton would be a singleton only outside the package.

Comment: I *think* he wants to write a group of singletons that all extend a single base class.

Comment: It is really not clear as the OP says : "I am looking for a way to implement an abstract class (or effectively abstract) that enforces only one instance of each subclass." So I concluded that the abstract class handles the instances of subclasses.

Comment: I agree. I have to admit it took me a bit of thinking to work out what the purpose of this base class is. I'm left thinking that it's the wrong class that checking for singletons. A private constructor in the derived class would sort this.

Comment: To be more precise, I did not expect my base class to be a singleton, my goal was to enforce any subclass to be a singleton. But I was curious whether doing so was possible without strong bidirectional coupling as you pointed out. from your, and others answers, it doesn't seem like java provides a clean way of doing this.

Answer (score -1):

I wanted to say, that singletons are bad. But found this problem interesting, So I created what you want.
Here is the code

```
  public static abstract class SingletonBase {
        private static HashSet<SingletonBase> instances = new HashSet<>();

        {
            for (SingletonBase sb : instances) {
                if (sb.getClass() == this.getClass()) throw new RuntimeException("there is already 1 instance");
            }
        }

        public static <E> E getInstance(Class<E> clazz) {
            if (!SingletonBase.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)) {
                throw new RuntimeException();
            }
            for (SingletonBase sb : instances) {
                if (sb.getClass() == clazz) return (E) sb;
            }

            try {
                return clazz.newInstance();
            } catch (InstantiationException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;

        }

        private SingletonBase() {
            instances.add(this);
        }

    }
    static class SingletonTest extends SingletonBase{

    }

    static class SecondSingletonTest extends SingletonBase{

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(int i=0;i<=10;i++)
            System.out.println(  SingletonBase.getInstance(SingletonTest.class));
        for(int i=0;i<=10;i++)
            System.out.println(  SingletonBase.getInstance(SecondSingletonTest.class));
        //throws exception, because we try to create second instance here
        new SingletonTest();
    }
```

There are some problems with approach of creating generic class which are solved here:
first, you cannot create more than one instance, so base class has to keep track of all instances, and when you try to create another one using new, it will throw exception. Second, you need to get instance for a specific class. If you dont want to create instance like this:

```
SingletonBase.getInstance(SecondSingletonTest.class)
```

You can create subclasses like this:

```
 static class SingletonTest extends SingletonBase{
        public static  SingletonTest getInstance(){
            return getInstance(SingletonTest.class);
        }
    }
```

There was also suggested to use ENUM approach, it is easy to implement, but breakes open closed principle from SOLID

Comment: The only reason this works is because all your classes are sibling nested classes and can access the private constructor. Don't know why you didn't show it in the code snippet. This breaks the principle you mentioned much more then enum. You basically implemented yourself the same thing you get with enum for free.

Comment: @Oleg Well, you can change constructor to protected, and it will still work as a singleton base